# Opening Excelfile and save to Server

Tags: javascript, php, excel

is it possible with basic tools (php,js) to open an excelfile (or wordfile) form Web (not download, only open) and save it. It should be uploaded immediatly without any tasks (Upload Form etc.)

Any Ideas? I havnt found any solutions yet.

Comment: SharePoint integration is built-in into the MS Office applications. In theory, if you could mimic the SharePoint API's in your own php application, you could make this work. In practice, that is just too much work to be feasible, even for a large team.

Comment: Open? Or Upload? Those are two very different things. But in any case you can only open a Word or Excel file if the corresponsing Office application is installed and LICENSED. Note that the Office applications are NOT designed to run in a server environment so what you envision is not supported. Better would be to work directly with the Office Open XML file format which does not require the Office application, nor a license. This file format was designed with file manipulation in a server environment in mind. There is an Open XML SDK for JavaScript available.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I´m not really happy to embrace the resultion. I see, i can´t handle it for my own.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work in a WYSIWYG mode, consider using Google Docs or Google Sheets for such type of need.
Otherwise, you need to downnoad/edit/reupload it. 
If you know exactly where to write an update, you may use PHPExcel to open an existing file and update it through a PHP program.