# Open/save Excel file in directory

Tags: javascript, php, excel, directory

Can an Excel spreadsheet be opened from a shared network directory using PHP or JavaScript, so that when the file is saved, it will be saved back into that same directory?

I was offered this as a possible solution:

http://researchhubs.com/post/computing/javascript/open-a-local-file-with-javascript.html

Then I saw this question on Stack Overflow, but this question was talking about saving to a server:

[Opening Excelfile and save to Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34829252/opening-excelfile-and-save-to-server)

I don't think this can be done, but I need confirmation.

Comment: Javascript cannot access the clients hard disc, unless it's run from a browser addon. And even then it has very limited access. PHP cannot run without a server. But after you've installed a server, you can include the path to the file to it after which PHP is able to read / write to the file(s).

Comment: So as long as I have to pieces in place, I should be able to open an Excel file from a directory, and when I edit the file and save it, it'll save back into that same directory?

Comment: As long as you set it up right, yes. Once PHP has read / write permissions to the file path, it'll work perfectly fine.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP just wanted to know which language could accomplish the goal. I don't believe this question holds any value for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a file from a share using php, you will have to provide the path to it. You can not open a file from the computer in javascript, the user have to select the file in order to javascript have access to it.

Again, if you have access from the server to the share you can open, edit, write that file if the webserver have access to read/write it.

Comment: If you think the answer was what you was looking for you can mark it as answered to let other users knows.

Comment: @Vidal No begging for checkmarks. OP is well within his right to wait for better, more detailed answers. Aside from that, this question will most likely be closed because it's off topic. There's no programming question, just some general info one could easily find anywhere. So any reputation you receive for this will be removed later on anyway :)

Comment: It was indeed just a general question.  Thank you, sir.